# Show a confirmation page before complete function call

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have written a module for our club. What i have now is a page that displays a html table showing the availability of club room

I have added a link to the last column of that table [reference code sample] that when clicked will let the user change the value from yes to no. Shocking I got the updating of the query working, passing the parameters, but now I am stuck on the flow.

**The way it is working right now is:**

- User clicks link mentioned above
- it goes to my module/function, run its, which changes the value from 'Y' to 'N'
- then it goes to my change_availability_test that list in the module/function

**what I want is**:

- User clicks link
- goes to [change_availability_test] page that asks, Are you sure you want to change the availability?
- User has the option to click a "Change availability" button, that then runs the module/function and they are returned to the original page that's displaying the html table or if they click a "No" no action taken, just returned to the original page that's displaying the html table.

List item

```
$items['/change_availability/%'] = array(
       'title' => 'Change Availability',
       'page callback' => 'change_availability_test',
       'access arguments' => array('user_access'),
       'page arguments' => array(2),
       'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
         );

 return $items;
}

   /**
    * Change space availability status.
    */
   function change_availability_test($rid = NULL, ) {

     //This function runs the db update query.
   }

    if ($form['rid']) {
       foreach (element_children($form['rid']) as $key) {
         $rows[] = array(
           'data' => array(
             drupal_render($form['rid'][$key]),
             drupal_render($form['squad_name'][$key]),
             drupal_render($form['task_id'][$key]),
             drupal_render($form['email'][$key]),
             drupal_render($form['club_location'][$key]),
             drupal_render($form['rating'][$key]['grade']),
             l(t('click'), "change_availability/".$key),
           ),
           'class' => $form['status'][$key]['#value'],
         );
         }
       $headers = array(
         array('data' => t('id')),
         array('data' => t('squad_name')),
         array('data' => t('task_id')),
         array('data' => t('email')),
         array('data' => t('Club Location')),
         array('data' => t('Rating')),
         array('data' => t('Available?')),
       );

       $output = theme('table', $header, $rows, array('id' => 'room-listing'));
       $output .= drupal_render($form);
     }
     return $output;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add confirmation form to your page. There is a Drupal API function for this - [confirm_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/confirm_form/7), that helps you create such form.

Change your code to like this:

```
// In your hook_menu().
$items['change_availability/%'] = array(
  'title' => t('Change Availability'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('change_availability_test_form', 1),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;


/**
 * Form callback for 'change_availability/%' path.
 */
function change_availability_test_form($form, $form_state, $account) {
  $form['account'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $account,
  );

  return confirm_form($form, t('Are you sure you want to change the availability?'), 'here_goes_your_backurl_for_cancel_link');
}

/**
 * Submit callback for 'change_availability_test_form' form.
 */
function change_availability_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $account = $form_state['values']['account'];
  // Call your function
  change_availability_test($account);
  // Redirect back to te table.
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'your_backurl';
}
```